# C++ Calculator class code review/advise. Is the design of this class wrong?

Tags: c++, class, calculator

I came across a rather simple question of writing a basic calculator class in C++.
I wrote a solution which works fine, but I feel is overcomplicated(maybe).

I mean should the abstraction of calculator class be related to only the operations(+,-,/,* etc) and should the input data not be associated with object itself?

Please help to review it, also let me know if returning an lvalue in overloaded operators is fine or it should return an object?

Also I have written main function to test the code for now and not focused to provide interactive options(user inputs/print statements)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;

const long long INF = LLONG_MAX;

class Calculator{
    double input1;
public:

    Calculator(double inp1 = 0.0d): input1(inp1)
    {

    }

    double operator+(const Calculator& obj){
        return this->input1 + obj.input1;
    }
    double operator-(const Calculator& obj){
        return this->input1 - obj.input1;
    }
    double operator*(const Calculator& obj){
        return this->input1 * obj.input1;
    }
    double operator/(const Calculator& obj){
        if(0 == obj.input1) return INF;
        return this->input1 / obj.input1;
    }
    double operator%(const Calculator& obj){
        if(0 == obj.input1) return INF;
        return fmod(this->input1, obj.input1);
    }
    double operator^(const Calculator& obj){
        return pow(this->input1, obj.input1);
    }
    
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,const Calculator& re);

};

    ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream,const Calculator& re){
        stream<<re.input1;
        return stream;
    }

int main(){
    Calculator obj1(5.0);
    Calculator obj2(4.0);
    Calculator res = (obj2 ^ obj1 ); 
    cout<< res <<endl;

}
```

Comment: Probably best on code review.stackexchange.com since the code works.

Comment: "The result of adding a calculator and a calculator is a `double`" sounds quite strange to me, but so does "if you add two calculators you get a new calculator".

Comment: A calculator is a device that performs calculations. One does not calculate calculators, so I think your abstraction is ill conceived.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about reviewing working code belong on [codereview.se]. Just make sure you state your objectives clearly in the question if you decide to post there.

Comment: @molbdnilo, ahhh now you put it this way, I understand what's wrong with it, thanks

Comment: Add templatization, so it the type can be chosen on object creation. What if i want integers only and not bothering with the noise what double causes. Not to mention that double is not an exact representation of numbers, you could end up with many scientific notation values to cover the tiny differences. All in all, introduce templatization and precision control.